# How can I get built-in operator as a function?

Tags: go, functional-programming, operators

###### The goal

How can I get a built-in operator as a function?
I want to take advantage of functional programming.
I have some files with vectorizing functions (eg. *Remap[inT any](sl []inT, f func(inT) inT)*), which take a scalar function to apply on every element of one or two slices.

###### I know I could:

```
func eq(a, b int)bool{
   return a==b
}
```

and hope that after inlining there'll be no overhead.

But I prefer a short, performant & consistent way, if exists.

- In Python 3 I would:
  `int.__eq__`
- In Rust I would:
  `i32::eq`
- In C++ I would:

```
   #include <functional>
   /*code here*/
   std::equal_to<int>()
```

###### How would you achieve this in Go?

Comment: This looks very much like an XY problem. What is your actual goal? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Flimzy I added another bold header to make my goal clear & obvious.
I'm surprised with your comment, I thought that the title question "How can I get built-in operator as a function?" says everything.

Comment: No. You're still asking an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  I'm asking: What is your GOAL. That is: What do you want to do with a built-in operator as a function? What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: Unfortunately "you can't" is the correct answer. The other two linked questions offer alternatives.

Comment: Implemented at https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tawesoft/golib/v2/operator e.g. `operator.Add[int]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get built-in operator as a function? Any `functional` package in Go?

You cannot.